# Ruby Zlib compression gives different outputs for the same input

Tags: ruby, compression, gzip, zlib

I have this ruby method for compressing a string -

```
    def compress_data(data)
        output = StringIO.new
        gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(output)
        gz.write(data)
        gz.close

        compressed_data = output.string
        compressed_data
    end
```

When I call this method with the same input, I get different outputs at different times. I am trying to get the byte array for the compressed outputs and compare them. 
The output is `Different` when I run the below -

```
input = "hello world"

output1 = (compress_data input).bytes.to_a
sleep 1
output2 = (compress_data input).bytes.to_a
if output1 == output2
    puts 'Same'
else
    puts 'Different'
end
```

The output is `Same` when I remove the sleep. Does the compression algorithm have something to do with the current time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1 - fixed mtime:

Yes. The compression time is stored in the header. You can use the `mtime` method to set the time to a fixed value, which will resolve your problem:

```
gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(output)
gz.mtime = 1
gz.write(data)
gz.close
```

Note that [the Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/GzipWriter.html#method-i-mtime-3D) says that setting `mtime` to zero will disable the timestamp. I tried it, and it does not work. I also looked at the source code, and it appears this functionality is missing. Seems like a bug. So you have to set it to something else than 0 (but see comments below - it will be fixed in future releases).

#### Option 2 - skip the header:

Another option is to just skip the header when checking for similar data. The header is 10 bytes long, so to only check the data:

```
data = compress_data(input).bytes[10..-1]
```

Note that you do not need to call `to_a` on `bytes`. It is already an Array:

> String.bytes -> an_array
>
> Returns an array of bytes in str.  This is a shorthand for str.each_byte.to_a.

Comment: [It has been fixed one month ago.](https://github.com/ruby/zlib/pull/10).

Comment: I checked the current releases and it is not yet included. So it will be in in Ruby 2.6.6 or 2.7.0 most likely.

Comment: They could also publish a new version of the `zlib` gem. Somebody just has to ask for it as I don't believe they have a schedule or plans (like for Ruby releases).

Comment: Thanks! I was actually writing a test case for the compression method when I found out this issue. Ignoring the header bytes while comparison solves my problem.